# MySQL: Calculate the duration for multiple statuses

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, aggregate, datediff

I have a database that contains member information for a club. Each member at any time can be one of three distinct statuses (active, veteran, associate).  I have it broken down into three tables.  The member table, with all the member information, the status table with the status_name and status_id and a grid table which includes the member_id, status_id, date_from and date_to.

I am trying to calculate the amount of time a member has spent at each status.  I am currently calculating the total time that the member has spent in the "active" status via the following query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, 
 (DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( SUM( DATEDIFF( IFNULL( q.date_to, NOW() ) , q.date_from ) ) ) , "%Y" ) +0) as service_years 
 FROM member a
 LEFT JOIN member_status q on a.id = q.member_id AND q.status_id = 1
 GROUP BY a.id
```

I know that I can pull the total time that the person has been a member by leaving off the AND in the left join, however I can't figure out a way to calculate the time for each status in a single query.

My ideal result would be along the lines of:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 |member_name | active_years | veteran_years | total_years |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 |name        | 5            | 5             | 10          |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 1=active and 2=veteran, something like this should work:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, 
 (DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( SUM( case when q.status_id = 1 then DATEDIFF( IFNULL( q.date_to, NOW() ) , q.date_from ) ) else 0 end ) , "%Y" ) +0) as active_years,
 (DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( SUM( case when q.status_id = 2 then DATEDIFF( IFNULL( q.date_to, NOW() ) , q.date_from ) ) else 0 end ) , "%Y" ) +0) as veteran_years,
(DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( SUM( DATEDIFF( IFNULL( q.date_to, NOW() ) , q.date_from ) ) ) , "%Y" ) +0) as total_years 
 FROM member a
  LEFT JOIN member_status q on a.id = q.member_id AND q.status_id in (1,2)
 GROUP BY a.id
```

Another option is to join the member_status table more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this which uses a `CASE` statement to determine the status name and then calculates the total number of years based on the status:

```
SELECT first_name, 
  last_name, 
  CASE WHEN status_name = 'active' 
    then (DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( SUM( DATEDIFF( IFNULL( q.date_to, NOW() ) , q.date_from ) ) ) , "%Y" ) +0) end as active_years,
  CASE WHEN status_name = 'veteran' 
    then (DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( SUM( DATEDIFF( IFNULL( q.date_to, NOW() ) , q.date_from ) ) ) , "%Y" ) +0) end as active_years,
  (DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( SUM( DATEDIFF( IFNULL( q.date_to, NOW() ) , q.date_from ) ) ) , "%Y" ) +0) as total_years,
FROM member a
LEFT JOIN member_status q 
  on a.id = q.member_id 
  AND q.status_id = 1
GROUP BY a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name
```

*if you post some sample data it will be easier to determine the proper query*